# How can I add text element and link element in JavaScript in one line

Tags: javascript

I have a following code within the JavaScript file

```
o.a.createElement("p", null, "My text"),
o.a.createElement("a", { href: "http://www.google.com" }, "here"),
```

I would like to end up having a one line saying "My text here". Instead I end up having the link "here" underneath the "My text" text.

What can I do to have "My text" text and the link "here" in one line?

Comment: Not sure what's happening after you create the `a` element, but seems like you can use [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to do this.

Comment: try giving "p" a "display: inline;" style

Comment: @IsoW that would not be the best approach - since we can actually accomplish this in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`P`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) Tags in HTML are always [***Block level elements***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), So You need  to use [**`span`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) which is [***Inline elements***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)

```
o.a.createElement("span", null, "My text"),
o.a.createElement("a", { href: "http://www.google.com" }, "here"),
```

***Note:** A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).*

Answer (score 0):

You can directly append HTML code

```
o.a.innerHTML += `<p>My text <a href="http://www.google.com">here</a></p>`
```

This is one line and you can do some more stuff with this.
But I believe those are only looks.

".innerHTML" changed html code of the element so it's better to be careful what you append. For instance when it comes to populating the data from a sever you'd better sanitize the data beforehand